# I want the value of "title" that should be "pipeline-pr-test" and value of "pr" that should be "2" from below code by using shell and jq?

Tags: json, shell, github, jq, pull-request

```json
[
  {
    "name": "pr",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "title",
    "value": "pipeline-pr-test"
  },
  {
    "name": "headhhf",
    "value": "60dd35gt6"
  },
  {
    "name": "base",
    "value": "air"
  },
  {
    "name": "basha",
    "value": "7yhfr7e85a0cc"
  }
]
```

Comment: Try `jq -r 'INDEX(.name)["title", "pr"].value'` on jq 1.6+

Comment: I want output like below and this data is in test.json file.

Title = pipeline-pr-test
PR = 2

Comment: What logic do you expect to capitalize `title` on the first letter to `Title` while `pr` on all letters to `PR`? Apart from the capitalization issue, you could use string interpolation: `INDEX(.name)["title", "pr"] | "\(.name) = \(.value)"`

Answer (score 2):

Below query help me to get an output:

```
jq -r 'INDEX(.name)["title", "pr"] | "\(.name) = \(.value)"' test.json
```

Comment: If you use `"\(.name)=\(.value | @sh)"`, then the output will be in a form that you can `source` into the shell and use the variables directly